# How do I properly give a navigation bar and tab bar a background image?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift5

So I'm trying to replicate the iOS 6 Game Center (For iOS 12 and up) app right now and I'm struggling with the tab bar and navigation bar.

With the code I have so far it comes out like this on the iPhone Xr
[image]

```swift
//This puts the iOS 6 Game Center image in a UIImage.
let navigationAndTabBarImage = UIImage(named: "GameCenterNavigationAndTabBarStyle")!
//This sets the content mode to scale to fill which is supposed to stretch out the image to fit.
UITabBar.appearance().contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
//This changes the tab bar's background image to navigationAndTabBarImage.
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = navigationAndTabBarImage
//This sets the content mode to scale to fill which is supposed to stretch out the image to fit.
UINavigationBar.appearance().contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
//This changes the navigation bar's background image to navigationAndTabBarImage.
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navigationAndTabBarImage, for: .default)
```

but as you see the tab bar doesn't just stretch to the bottom instead it repeats even though I set the content mode to scaleToFill so it would stretch (and on other screen sizes the navigation bar and/or tab bar mess up so the problem persists with both). To clarify I would like the image to repeat horizontally but stretch down vertically.